# What is the general difference between methods and types in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating an online app, which required some C# code. So I created a new file name: User.cs, in that file I am having this code:

```
public class UserProperties {
    public string hasPermission (string permission) {
        // get the permissions of the user
        var db = Database.Open("VMS");
        var roles = db.Query("SELECT * FROM webpages_UsersInRoles 
        WHERE UserId =@0", WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
        // Get the Role Id
        var getRole = "";
        foreach (var row in roles) {
            getRole = row.RoleId.ToString();
        }
        // Get the permission ID
        var permissions = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Permissions WHERE 
        LOWER(Permission_Name) = LOWER(@0)", permission);
        var permissionId = "";
        foreach (var row in permissions) {
            permissionId = row.Permission_Id.ToString();
        }
        // Now get the rolePermissions
        var role_permissions = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Role_Permissions 
        WHERE Role_Id =@0 AND Permission_Id =@1", getRole, permissionId);
        if(role_permissions.Count() == 0) {
            return "Not Allowed.";
        } else {
            return "Yes, full permission.";
        }
    }
}
```

This code would look for the user's permissions and then return a value. But its not happening. When I try to execute it:

```
@{ 
  new UserProperties.hasPermission("Create_Page");
}
```

It gives me an exception of:

> CS0118: 'User.hasPermission(string)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'

I am not sure how am I using it as a type?

Comment: The compiler is confused. You tell him to create a new, oh no, get the value of some method.

Comment: I suggest you start reading about [Object Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) and start by doing small `Hello, World!` type of applications before getting into complex Web stuff.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, yes you're right. I was just missing that paranthesis..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use:

```
new UserProperties().hasPermission("Create_Page")
```

alternatively, you could make `hasPermission` static, then you won't need to create an instace

```
public static string hasPermission (string permission) { ... }

@{ 
  UserProperties.hasPermission("Create_Page");
}
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks alot! :) I am really gonna use `static` and your code :) Thanks brother...

Answer (score 2):

The first line your code:

```
public class UserProperties
```

Defines a (object) Type.

The next line you declare an *instance* method.

```
public string hasPermission (string permission)
```

Unless you create an instance of UserProperties..

```
var userProperties = new UserProperties();
```

You can't call `hasPermission()`.

You could alternatively (not recommended) create a static method.

```
public static string hasPermission (string permission)
```

[MSDN Docs 10.5.2 - Static and instance methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645766%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add parentheses:

```
@{ 
  new UserProperties().hasPermission("Create_Page");
}
```

`new UserProperties()` creates an instance of the `UserProperties` class, which you then call the `hasPermission` method on.

If `hasPermission` were defined as `static` then your syntax would be valid (you don't need an instance to call the method on).

Answer (score 0):

u will have to create an instance of UserProperties.

```
var up = new UserProperties();
up.hasPermission("Create_Page");
```

or just

```
new UserProperties().hasPermission("Create_Page");
```